# It is possible to group vbulletin subforums on categories?

Tags: forum, vbulletin

I saw in vbulletin admincp a option Category manager and I added a few categories.
 On homepage I added the category widget.

My question is: Why these categories are useful? What is their scope? Could I
 group some subforums under a category?

Thank you